# Notifying/Alerting a user the element is already in use?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a bright/white background, and dark/black background. I made a button to switch between them when you click on it. I tried to make an alert or notification when the user click the same button or use the same background. But it seems like the alert is showing up even when the user just clicked on the button. I'll appreciate any replies.

Here is my code:

```js
var x = 2;

function chngBg1() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  var x = 1;
  if (x == 1) {
    alert('This bg is already in use.');
  }
}

function chngBg2() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  var x = 0;
  if (x == 0) {
    alert('This bg is already in use.');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="bgbuttons">
    <button type="button" onclick="chngBg1()">
      White background
    </button>
    <button type="button" onclick="chngBg2()">
      black background
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
```

**[Note: I used true/false method to do it]**

Comment: What is with those `var x = ...` _in_ the functions? They make no sense at all. The `x` in the `if` condition is the `x` from the line above so the condition will always evaluate as `true`

Comment: I know, but this is the only thing I can make to do it. I need to make the value of `x` to change to `1` on the next button click so it can work fine. @Andreas

Comment: You don't need `var` to change the content of a variable. And changing the variable _before_ comparing it doesn't help.

Comment: If you only have two options, why don't you make the button a toggle that switches between them?

Comment: Another UX solution would be to use a switch, and assume that light mode is the default, and let the user toggle to dark mode by clicking the switch. When programming, try to solve issues with design first, then fallback to code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is logical error in your code. And also, you should check for background color in the `if` statements. Here is the fixed code-

```js
function chngBg1() {
  if (document.body.style.backgroundColor == 'white') {
    alert('This bg is already in use.');
  }
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
}

function chngBg2() {
  if (document.body.style.backgroundColor == 'black') {
    alert('This bg is already in use.');
  }
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="bgbuttons">
    <button type="button" onclick="chngBg1()">
      White background
    </button>
    <button type="button" onclick="chngBg2()">
      black background
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
```

In your code, you are setting v = 1 every time the page loads, so when you check it with the `if` statement, it is already equal to 1 (because you just set it to 1 in the previous line, remember?)

Also, you should have check for the current background color using `document.body.style.backgroundColor`
I have fixed the code.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Now it works perfectly fine, @Dev.Mehul

Answer (score 1):

`var x` needs to be initialized only once. I have added conditions in both functions that helps solve your problem.

```js
var x = 1;

  function chngBg1() {
    if (x === 1) {
      alert("This bg is already in use.");
    } else {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      x = 1;
    }
  }

  function chngBg2() {
    if (x === 0) {
      alert("This bg is already in use.");
    } else {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
      x = 0;
    }
  }
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="bgbuttons">
    <button type="button" onclick="chngBg1()">White background</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="chngBg2()">black background</button>
  </div>
</body>
```